# ROR 3 defining foreign key relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial on how to define basic foreign key relationships between models. suppose I have a User model and a Game model..

I would like to define two fields in the Game model - host_id and visitor_id which are mapped via foreign key relationship to the User model. The IDs of the 'host' and 'visitor' fields of the Game class basically define the two players which will engage in a peer-to-peer game... and those fields need to be mapped to actual users of the application as defined in the User model by userID..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Did try this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html?
I think it could be like this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :game
end
class Game
  has_one :host_user, :class_name => "User"
  has_one :visit_user, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! another requirement I have is a User may partake in many games... so how do i go about adding that? can a User belong_to :game   as well as    has_many :games ?

Comment: For this purpose you should read about has_and_belongs_to_many association.